# Serval Issues/Errors when declaring in a new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Swift 2, xcode7

Added a second ViewController in my project. The first view controller uses almost the same line of code.

Getting these errors:

> Getter for 'tableView' with Objective-C selector 'tableView' conflicts with getter for 'tableView' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector
>
> Overriding let must be as accessible as its enclosing type
>
> Cannot override mutable property 'tableView' of type 'UITableView!' with covariant type 'UITableView'

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AllChatsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext?
    
    private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController?
    
    private let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)//errors are here
    
    
    private let cellIdentifier = "MessageCell"
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: `UITableViewController`'s view is a `UITableView` whose instance name is tableView (i.e. you can already say `self.tableView` without the line the throws the error, with that line in the compile won't know what tableView you are referring to). Thus, it's not necessary and not possible to have an instance property name tableView in a subclass of `UITableViewController`. Subclass `UIViewController` if you feel that you need a table view that does not take up the entire view of your view controller.

Comment: Thanks! So why does this line of code work in my other view controller then?

Comment: Probably because that is a subclass of UIViewController which does not have a property named tableView. You would see a similar error if you added a variable view of type UIView to that view controller as a UIViewController already has a property called view.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it fixed. I needed UIViewController, not UITableViewController....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beywulf was correct, I changed the VC to a TVC and it is working now